# How to get collection count of mongodb with just one cli/bash command?

Tags: mongodb, bash

How to get  collection count of mongodb with just one cli/bash command?

I know we can get the above kind of output with the Postgresql database using the below syntax.

```
psql -U postgres testdb -c "select id from org where email='user11@yahoo.com';"
```

How can we do the same thing in MongoDB with one cli/bash command.

Tried the below/above similar command but don't know the exact syntax

```
mongo testdb -c "db.user.count();"
```

getting below unrecognised option error.

```
Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '-c'
```

what's the right syntax to get the desired output with just one cli/bash command?